# Assign value to a multi-column combobox vba on load

Tags: vba, ms-access, combobox

I know it's so naive to ask this, but I am stuck in her and no solution found on the internet. I have a combobox in which I have 4 colmns 3 of them are invisible and one is. In the visible colomn I would like to display the value of pname(a string) on load of form.
I tried:

```
 cboPlanName.value=pname
 cboPlanName=pname 
 cboPlanName.text=pname
```

With the first two line the combobox diplays nothing but with .text property it gives me an errror (2135 property read-only impossible to define it).

What do you suggest?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Where have you put said code, in `Form_Load`?

Comment: In the **sub Form_Open** @Nathan_Sav

Comment: does pname have a value, is it within the list, limit to list etc.?  can you show a bit more in your code.

Comment: No pname is not in the list, it's a string that containt a value like 'test'. I would like to siplay this value in the combobox when the form loads @Nathan_Sav

Comment: @Marwan see my answer below, let me know if that wokks for you ?

Comment: You need to check that it's in the list, if limit to list, so add if not as the answer shows.

Comment: In this List i have 4  colmns 3 of them are invisible and one is. In the visible colomn I would like to display the value of pname, I treid the solution and it's still not working @Nathan_Sav

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well I finally found the solution knowing that it's a combobox of 4 columns, 3 of them are hidden. What I've done is that I made a loop through the values of the shown column of the combobox and when the value matchs with the string(pname), I set the selected value of the combobox to the value that matched, in other words the values are in the list, the code looks for the equal value to the string(pname) and selects it.

```
    For j = 0 To cboPlanName.ListCount - 1
      IF cboPlanName.Column(1, j) = pname Then
         Me.cboPlanName = cboPlanName.ItemData(j)
      End If
    Next j
```

And thanks for those who tried to help, I really appreciate it:)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an item to a combobox like this:

```
cboPlanName.AddItem pname
```

If `pname` is an array of values then

```
For Each pnameVal in pname
     cboPlanName.AddItem pnameVal.Value
Next pnameVal
```

*Update from comments:*

You will need to add pname to a `public` rather than `Dim`, at the top of your userform enter `Public pname as string` (or just `Public pname` if it holds more than just a string) or if the value comes from a Sub ina  module then you will need to add `Public pname as string` to the top of the module rather than the userform, this will allow the variable to be passed to another Sub without losing its value

Comment: When I add the value to the list it gives me an error: The property origin source must be set to the value list values to use this method. It's not possible to display the value without adding it to the list ? @Mr.Burns

Comment: At the start of the Sub or just before you try to add `pname` to the combobox enter this `Debug.Print pname` and let me know what value is returned (`Crtl + G` to see what value is returned) @Marwan

Comment: It gives the value wanted value **test**. I tried to write the code in form Form_Activate() but it seems the code is not excuting and when I write it in Sub Form_Open() it crashes.@Mr.Burns

Comment: @Marwan I understand now, give me a few min and I will update my answer

Comment: Still it doesn't work, I modified my questuon plase have a look at it maybe you can see where is the problem. BTW i am not passing the value from aform to other form @Mr.Burns